# How to? Playwright return the element to be use in another file (page object model)

Tags: playwright

So I have a script that I would like to return the element to be use in the other file. For example below:

Protractor:

```
Element file:
login() {
    return $( '.modal-footer .btn.btn-primary' );
}
    

Page file:
loginPage(){
    elementPage.login().click()
}

Playwright: How to do it in playwright?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These suggestions did not work for me. I had to do the following in order for it to work properly.

```
// Element file:
login() {
    return page.locator( '.modal-footer .btn.btn-primary' );
}
    

// Page file:
async loginPage(){
    await (await elementPage.login()).click()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this guide](https://playwright.dev/docs/protractor) for a comprehensive description of how to migrate from Protractor to Playwright.

You example will change to something like this

```js
// Element file:
login() {
    return page.locator( '.modal-footer .btn.btn-primary' );
}
    

// Page file:
async loginPage(){
    await elementPage.login().click()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A great example here:

https://playwright.dev/docs/test-pom

Reusable methods and locators